# std::vector; cannot convert parameter; Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2012, std

I am getting an error with VS2012 x64 express edition. The same code works correctly under VS2010. I have been going through many threads here at stackoverflow and it seems a bug in VS2012.

The code:

```
typedef vector< vector<cv::Point2d> > vec_type; 
vec_type table;
table.assign( 100, 0 );
```

Error:

> error C2664: '`void std::vector<_Ty>::assign(unsigned __int64, const std::vector<cv::Point2d> &)`' : cannot convert parameter 2 from '`int`' to '`const std::vector<_Ty> &`'

Please can anyone point out solution or workaround this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a bug in VC++ 2012, this is a standards conformance _improvement_ – in C++11 `std::vector<>`'s constructor signature changed and the code you have _shouldn't_ work.

Comment: I have to ask: What was that code supposed to do?

Comment: @pmr : It was supposed to initialize `table` with 100 empty `vector<cv::Point2d>`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vec_type` element is `vector<cv::Point2d>` type, you can't assign `0` to it, the workaround solution can be:

pass `vector<Point2d>` default constructor

```
table.assign(100, vector<Point2d>());
```

Or use [std::vector::resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to get same effort:

```
table.resize(100);
```